# Julia: How do you add/subtract distribution functions?

Tags: julia

As part of a mini-project where I am numerically solving a linear differential equation, I have to subtract a probability distribution from another distribution. Is there a way to do this in Julia? When I try:

```
a = Chi(3) - Uniform(0,1)
```

There is no method set up for this:

```
MethodError: no method matching -(::Chi{Float64}, ::Uniform{Float64})
Closest candidates are:
  -(::UnivariateDistribution, ::Real) at C:\Users\Acer\.julia\packages\Distributions\Fl5RM\src\univariate\locationscale.jl:139
  -(::ChainRulesCore.AbstractThunk, ::Any) at C:\Users\Acer\.julia\packages\ChainRulesCore\sHMAp\src\tangent_types\thunks.jl:30
  -(::ChainRulesCore.ZeroTangent, ::Any) at C:\Users\Acer\.julia\packages\ChainRulesCore\sHMAp\src\tangent_arithmetic.jl:101
  ...
```

Comment: Assuming your distributions are independent you are essentially asking for their convolution. I have not checked but it is likely that the convolution of `Chi` and `Uniform` distribution does not have a tabulated closed form. If this is the case then the best you can do is to either derive the formulas yourself (it this is possible) or use custom numerical approximation or simulation (depending on your use case). The Distributions.jl package offers the `convolve` function but it has a limited functionality to a few standard convolutions that have a closed form.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Do you it will likely result in a closed form if instead of taking the convolution of `Chi` and `Uniform`, I take the convolution of `Normal` and `Uniform` using `convolve`? Where is the documentation for `convolve`? Do I have to negate  one of my arguments to "subtract" the distributions?

Answer (score 0):

As I have said the `convolve` function is defined in Distributions.jl. Here is a documentation: https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/convolution/. However this is not enough for your purposes as commented above.

Let me help you deriving the PDF of `Chi(3)-Uniform(0,1)` assuming they are independent.

Let `X` be the distribution you want, then we do `Chi(3)+Uniform(-1,0)` have its PDF as: `f(x) = C(z+1)-C(x)`. Where `C` is CDF of `Chi(3)` distribution.

So there is a closed form for PDF of your distribution in terms of CDF of Chi(3).

(I am doing the computations in my head so it would be good if you double checked them)